# Divide by zero exception in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code and it thow an divide by zero exception. How I can correct that and improve the code?

```
List<RelacionEjecucionPendientes> iniciativasEjecucionPendienteses = actividades
.GroupBy(cl => cl.iniciativaName)
.Select(cl => new RelacionEjecucionPendientes
{
    Nombre = cl.Key,
    ATiempoEjecucionCantidad = cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) >= 0),
    ATiempoEjecucionPorcentaje = String.Format("{0:0}", 
        (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) >= 0) /
         cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1))
}).ToList();
```

Comment: What is so magic? find your divisor and see why it is zero.

Comment: yes but I have cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1 but it does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add parentheses to group your conditional operator.  Division comes before the conditional (`? :`) operator, so it is trying to divide by 0 *before* the operator:

```
           ATiempoEjecucionPorcentaje = String.Format("{0:0}", 
                        (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) >= 0) /
                        (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1)))
```

Comment: [Order of Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) for reference